# Breadth first search cycling in rush hour solver when no solution is available

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a rush hour solving algorithm using breadth first search to traverse a graph of the different paths, stopping when a solution has been found.

After numerous tests, I've come across a problem I have no idea how to solve. When there is a solution, the algorithm works very well, but when none can be found, it just endlessly cycles because it recreates "nodes" that contain the same information as older ones, instead of returning towards the older ones if the information is the same. How would I be able to make it stop when it figures out there are no more possibilities?

Here are the classes I am using for the solver:

This is the main class RushHour, the one I run.
package rush.hour;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RushHour
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String fileName = "Parking.txt";
        String line;
        int lineNumber = 0;

        int numOfCars;
        List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNumber += 1;
//                System.out.println(lineNumber);
                System.out.println(line);
                if (lineNumber == 15)
                    numOfCars = Integer.parseInt(
                            line.substring(line.length() - 1)) + 1;
                if (lineNumber >= 17)
                {
                    String[] splitLine = line.split(":");
                    char[] coordinates = splitLine[1].toCharArray();
                    int a = coordinates[3] - 48;
                    int b = coordinates[5] - 48;
                    int c = coordinates[10] - 48;
                    int d = coordinates[12] - 48;
                    Car car = new Car(lineNumber - 17, a, b, c, d);
                    carsList.add(car);
                }
            }
            Parking parking = new Parking(carsList);
            Graph graph = new Graph(parking);
            List<Parking> sol = graph.bfs();
            System.out.println("\n------------- Solution -------------");
            for (Parking sols: sol)
            {   // L = Left, D = Down, R = Right, U = Up
                System.out.println(sols);
            }
        }


        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
            {ex.printStackTrace();}
        catch(IOException ex) 
            {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

And this is the "graph" that uses the adapted BFS

```
package rush.hour;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Queue;


public class Graph
{
    Parking posDepart;

    public Graph(Parking parking)
    {
        posDepart = parking;
    }

    public List<Parking> bfs()
    {
        List<Parking> res = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<Parking> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(posDepart);
        while (!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            Parking next = queue.remove();
            if (next.isFinal())
            {
                res.add(next);
                return next.getPath();
            }
            next.setChildren();
            for (Parking child : next.children) {
                queue.add(child);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

This is the Graph's "node", it represents the disposition of the cars on the board

```
package rush.hour;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Parking
{
    Parking father = null;
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean visited = false;
    List<Parking> children = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Character> move = new ArrayList<>();


    public Parking(List<Car> list)
    {
        for (Car car: list)
            carsList.add(car.clone());
    }

    public Parking(Parking vader,List<Character> mov)
    {
        for (Car car: vader.carsList)
            carsList.add(car.clone());
        father = vader;
        move = mov;
    }


    public void getNextParkings(List<List<Character>> moves)
    {   
        children.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); ++i)
        {
            List<Character> info = moves.get(i);
            Parking nextParking = new Parking(this, info);
            nextParking.carsList.get(info.get(0) - 48).move(info.get(1));
            children.add(nextParking);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String res = "";
        if (!move.isEmpty())
        {
            res += "Move made to reach this parking:";
            res += move;
            res += "\n";
        }
        for (Car car : carsList)
            res += car.toString();
        return res;
    }

    public boolean isFinal()
    {
        return carsList.get(0).isFinal();
    }

    public void setChildren()
    {
        if (children.isEmpty())
        {
            List<List<Character>> moves = getPossibleMoves();
            getNextParkings(moves);
        }
    }

    public List<List<Character>> getPossibleMoves()
    {
        List<List<Character>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Character>> moves;
        for (Car car : carsList)
        {
            moves = car.getPossibleMoves();
            for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); ++i)
            {
                List<Character> move = moves.get(i);
                if (!hasNeighbour(move.get(0), 
                        move.get(1) - 48, move.get(2) - 48))
                {
                    List<Character> foo = new ArrayList<>(2);
                    foo.add(car.getNumber());
                    foo.add(move.get(0));
                    res.add(foo);
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public boolean hasNeighbour(char direction, int x, int y)
    {
        for (Car car : carsList)
        {
            if (direction == 'U')
                if ((car.getX1() == x - 1 && car.getY1() == y) ||
                        (car.getX2() == x - 1 && car.getY2() == y))
                    return true;
            if (direction == 'D')
                if ((car.getX1() == x + 1 && car.getY1() == y) ||
                        (car.getX2() == x + 1 && car.getY2() == y))
                    return true;
            if (direction == 'L')
                if ((car.getX1() == x && car.getY1() == y - 1) ||
                        (car.getX2() == x && car.getY2() == y - 1))
                    return true;
            if (direction == 'R')
                if ((car.getX1() == x && car.getY1() == y + 1) ||
                        (car.getX2() == x && car.getY2() == y + 1))
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<Parking> getPath()
    {
        Parking temp_father;
        List<Parking> path = new LinkedList<>();
        path.add(this);
        temp_father = this.father;
        while (temp_father != null)
        {
            path.add(0, temp_father);
            temp_father = temp_father.father;
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

And finally the Car class, which probably isn't very important to the problem but still

```
package rush.hour;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Car
{
    char orientation;
    int carNumber;
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int y1; 
    int y2;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Car n° : " + (carNumber) + " : [(" + (x1) + ", " + y1 + ')' +
                " (" + (x2) + ", " + y2 + ")]" + "\n";
    }

    public Car clone()
    {
        Car c = new Car(carNumber, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        return c;
    }

    public Car(int n, int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        carNumber = n;
        if (a <= c)
        {
            x1 = a;
            x2 = c;
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = c;
            x2 = a;
        }
        if (b <= d)
        {
            y1 = b;
            y2 = d;
        }
        else
        {
            y1 = d;
            y2 = b;
        }
        if (x1 == x2)
            orientation = 'H';
        else
            orientation = 'V';
    }

        public char getNumber()
    {
        return Integer.toString(carNumber).charAt(0);
    }

    public int getX1()
    {
        return x1;
    }

    public int getX2()
    {
        return x2;
    }

    public int getY1()
    {
        return y1;
    }

    public int getY2()
    {
        return y2;
    }

    public void move(char direction)
    {
        if (direction == 'U')
        {
            --x1;
            --x2;
        }
        if (direction == 'D')
        {
            ++x1;
            ++x2;
        }
        if (direction == 'L')
        {
            --y1;
            --y2;
        }
        if (direction == 'R')
        {
            ++y1;
            ++y2;
        }
    }

    public boolean isFinal()
    {
        return y2 == 4 && carNumber == 0;
    }


    public List<List<Character>> getPossibleMoves()
    {
        List<List<Character>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        if (orientation == 'H')
        {
            if (y1 != 0)
            {
                List<Character> foo = new ArrayList<>(2);
                foo.add('L');
                foo.add(Integer.toString(x1).charAt(0));
                foo.add(Integer.toString(y1).charAt(0));
                res.add(foo);
            }
            if (y2 != 4)
            {
                List<Character> foo = new ArrayList<>(2);
                foo.add('R');
                foo.add(Integer.toString(x2).charAt(0));
                foo.add(Integer.toString(y2).charAt(0));
                res.add(foo);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (x1 != 0)
            {
                List<Character> foo = new ArrayList<>(2);
                foo.add('U');
                foo.add(Integer.toString(x1).charAt(0));
                foo.add(Integer.toString(y1).charAt(0));
                res.add(foo);
            }
            if (x2 != 4)
            {
                List<Character> foo = new ArrayList<>(2);
                foo.add('D');
                foo.add(Integer.toString(x2).charAt(0));
                foo.add(Integer.toString(y2).charAt(0));
                res.add(foo);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Excuse me if I've made some blatant styling/coding mistakes, I am more used to coding in Python/C++. Would there be a way to make this work?

Comment: Are you tracking visited configurations? That would do the trick and probably improve performance (unless the search space is very branchy and/or you run into memory limits).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes that was my initial idea, but since I'm creating a new node for every possibility, that wouldn't work :( 

For example if a car moves left, then it would be able to move back to the right, but that move is a new move and not returning to the old one.

Comment: @DefinitelyNotMe: There has to be a way to compare if the configurations are equal. Is time part of the configuration? If not, then comparison based on position alone is sufficient to tell if a state has been expanded already or not.

Comment: @AndyG It's alright I think I found my answer :D Though it's a bit inefficient. I check if the newly found move is in any of the father nodes, and don't add it to the list of possible moves if that's the case.

Comment: @DefinitelyNotMe: How do you define equivalence? I feel like we can help you design a more efficient structure.

Comment: Well a Parking (what serves as a Node) contains a list of Cars with their position on the board, so two Parkings that are the same would be two parkings that contain cars with the same positions. So if all possible solutions are explored I'd just like for the algorithm to stop instead of trying to solve the game with whatever positions I've used before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some type of data structure to keep track of paths already traversed. A hash table would be ideal and would provide a worst case of O(n) depending upon implementation. Not very familiar with Java but in C++ I would use std::unordered_map with the first field being a state of your board and the second being the number of moves at that point. I have implemented this algorithm before, and that's the approach I took. Incredibly fast.